# How to make the entries of abbreviation follow a fixed width style for short forms and long forms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I want to make my list of acronyms look like this.
[image: What I want to achive]
The following is what I have managed to implement.
I want the short form and long form have some *fixed width*.
The closest I've got to matching with the desired look is via

```
\renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{\item[\begin{tabular}{@{}p{8ex}@{}}\textbf{\glsentryshort{#1}}:\end{tabular}]{\glsentrylong{#1}}}
```

[image: What I've achieved, but with offset]
But now, the short form and the long form are no longer in horizontal alignment. The full form is slighly offset upward from the baseline.
The minimal working example kinda works but the implementation doesn't work in my actual work/thesis.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{bh}{BH}{Black Hole}
\newacronym{xb}{XB}{X-ray Binary}
\newacronym{bhc}{BHC}{Black Hole Candidate}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{\item[\begin{tabular}{@{}p{8ex}@{}}\textbf{\glsentryshort{#1}}:\end{tabular}]{\glsentrylong{#1}}}
\acrfull{bh} is an interesting astrophysical object. There are some \acrfull{xb} that host the \acrfull{bhc}.
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={\vspace{-3cm}\centering LIST OF ACRONYMS AND ABBREVIATIONS},nonumberlist]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you could try `\begin{tabular}[t]{…}` or replace the tabular by a box. But unfortunately I cannot test, because you have only shown a screenshot and a very, very short code snippet. Please, always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. We can always help best, if we can reproduce the problem by compiling the code, shown by the questioner. In your case, I'm almost sure, that there would be alternative suggestions maybe using another (maybe modified tabular) style.

Comment: @cabohah I've the snippet in MWE. It works in the MWE. Turns out I had `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` placed before the \printglossary. Creating a MWE solved the problem itself. Thanks.